# Angular 4 hidden div not working properly

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I 'm currently trying to make a simple login form using Bootstrap 4 / Angular 4. Thing is, basing my HTML template on the documentation available on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html, I cannot get the error messages to work if the input is empty. This is what I have so far:

```
<label>User Name:</label>
<input id="name"
    #name
    placeholder="user name" 
    class="form-control mb-md-3"
    (keyup.enter)="login(name.value, password.value)"
    name="username"
    required>
<div [hidden]="!name.valid || !name.pristine"
    class="alert alert-danger">User name is required</div>
```

I'm not sure if I need to have two-way binding to a model or anything, I'm not understanding the documentation fully. If it helps, I do have a class for it:

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public password: string
  ) {}
}
```

Also, for now this is not going to a service or anything, it's just a small demo screen that will support routing.

Comment: Yes, you should have 2-way binding. And you should not handle keyboard submission yourself. Just use ngSubmit on your form, and add a submit button, and it will work natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the ngModel directive. This can be bound to some object, or will just make .invalid, .valid, etc.. available to you. Also, you should reference this ngModel, not the input element.

This works:

```
<label>User Name:</label>
<input id="name"
   #name="ngModel"
   placeholder="user name"
   class="form-control mb-md-3"
   (keyup.enter)="login(name.value, password.value)"
   name="username" required
   ngModel>
<div *ngIf="name.invalid && name.dirty" class="alert alert-danger">User name is required</div>
```

Comment: Just one thing: this will submit the input values into the URL. Since I have a password field, is there a way I can avoid this? Adding method="post" in the form gives me a 404 error. What should I add?

Comment: Well, i don't know how exactly your login() method works, since the question is about Angular Forms. I suggest you to open another question and explain the broader context.